# Sharepoint Search: Return filtered list

Tags: sharepoint

I am just starting to get into SharePoint, and am still very much a beginner user. I've spent a couple of days figuring out how basic web parts and sites work.

Ultimately, the problem I'm trying to solve is that my company uses a List of "Job requests," with a file attached to each item in the List.

When I want to search for a previous job I did, I need to run a search for the text inside the attachment. Fortunately, the standard site search box can do this.

However, the way the results are presented is so awful as to be completely unusable. What I need is to be able to search the text inside the attachments, and then present to the user a filtered list of items featuring only the ones whose attachments contain the search terms.

I've spent several hours reading about Design Templates and how to set up searches, but I am severely hampered because I am not the SharePoint Administrator. I can't even begin to try out a lot of the things I find online because I don't have access to many of the settings.

I'm convinced the functionality that I want has to be possible, so I would appreciate any hints that might push me in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure that there's a good answer for you. Without being an administrator, your access to modify or enhance the underlying search service infrastructure is severely limited. You do have a lot of leeway when it comes to setting up and filtering views of lists, without using the search service at all, but of course this does not let you filter by attachment content. You'd be much better off in this scenario if the relevant information which is being embedded in the attachments were instead entered into a column on the list, but it sounds like that would require a business process change.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's unfortunate, but as you say, it looks like I'm going to be limited in what I can do here.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way of Search results displaying in a Design Templates. All you can able to create a new Query Rules. 
Also you can Query a document by Content using a KQL search. Create a new webpart, in this search a filter conditions in a document by KQL search. Obtain a ResultTable collection and bind it in your own grid as the way you want.

If you want to use only the default functionality, you need to understand the Query Rules and Design Templates. The way of displaying the search results can be controlled by Design Templates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't quite understand it. Especially this part: 

"in this search a filter conditions in a document by KQL search"

If you can explain it a little more simply, maybe this might help me.

Comment: In a newly created webpart, use KQL search to retrieve data. Use filter conditions as What the use enters. Like in your webpart add a textbox controls to get the user search term. This search term is the filter condition for your KQL search. use contains search in KQL.